# Terminal Not Working after installing SASS / COMPASS

Tags: macos, terminal

I just installed `Sass` and `compass`. I had to modify user permission in usr/bin so I typed in my  command line defaults write `com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` and changed the permission using the finder, then set it to false and hit `killall Finder` and but now I have an error that says

```
Last login: Tue May  7 21:54:50 on console
login(316,0x7fff7c35d960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f968b800860: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
```

Any idea what does it means and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What did you change the permissions to?

Comment: I changed the permission to the folder usr/bin yes

Comment: But what did you change them to? Ie, what are the permissions now?

Comment: I typed in the terminal com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE to see the file then in the file I did get info, went to privilege and change to read and write to everyone / weel and me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I changed the permissions of usr/bin and didn't change them back again. So by running Disk Utility on my mac solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete com.apple.terminal.plist from the ~/Library/Preference folder;
2. Open "Disk Utility" app -> Press "Repair Disk Permissions".

It will set default permissions for your `usr/bin` directory.